# Jing video continuous play

Tags: video, playback, continuous, jing

I have downloaded Jing video capture tool and captured a video of an application.
It creates a swf video file.
Our requirement is to allow the video to play continuously. 
Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks
vish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by continuous play? If you mean continuous recording, I'd try Camtasia out.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Continuous play is playing the same video non-stop.
Tried camtasia and got an avi file. Works fine.

Comment: Oh I understand what you are asking.  No I dont think there is a way yet.  I think it'd be a embed property that needs to be set.  There is "autoplay" value you can set to make it play without the button, but not sure if theres a value to play when it hits the end.

Comment: As soon as I typed that I found the answer: http://www.screencast.com/help/tutorial.aspx?id=490
The paramater is "loop=true" you need to add to the embed code